# vpn do not mask the original ip in gmails

Tags: vpn, gmail

I'm using IPVanish in Singapore.
I connected to a UK server, and indeed I've got a UK IP.
Then I signed for a brand new gmail address and tried to send out gmails to a friend in Singapore.

However my friend was able to see my original Singapore's ip address on the gmail header.

So, it seems IPVansh is not able to mask real ip in gmails. 
Is there any way to do so ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you set up the VPN correctly? Are you connecting through the VPN? Did you check your external IP address? (e.g. http://whatismyipaddress.com/ )

Comment: Yes, I'm connecting through the VPN and checked my ip and even my geolocation. Everythings is fine. It looks like I'm in UK. But if I send a gmail the gmail header contain the Singapore IP. I have also cleared all the cookies before sending the gmails.

Comment: I tried now IPVanish with a server in US. I've got an US IP and have checked my geo-location with "Where am I" http://ctrlq.org/maps/where/. Everyhing is fine. Then I cleared all cookies and registered another gmail address and sent gmails. Again the gmails header still contain the true Singapore address.

Answer (score 0):

It do work but it depends if your using free if your using free or that ip has been flagged free one have some time been flagged so they will not work i find cyberghost work well if you go premium + and its fast and easy and do not need a email to sign up.